# How can generate a list of dependencies from the src folder of a workspace?

Tags: ros, rosdep, packages, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

We have a large workspace with plenty packages coming from third party developers. At its moment, dependencies of those packages where solved using rosdep.

However, for documentation purposes we need the complete list of dependencies of all packages.

Is there a way of automatically generate that dependencies list? Something like an option on rosdep to not install anything, but just list all dependencies and output them to console or file.

So far I haven't find such a tool.

Thank you and best regards.

**Edit:**

Just tested `rosdep` with `--simulate --reinstall` options in a new workspace where some source has been placed.

First we run with `--simulate`:

```
rosdep install --simulate --from-paths ~/workspaces/project/src --ignore-src
#[apt] Installation commands:
  sudo -H apt-get install ros-indigo-hokuyo-node
```

It successfully list a ROS package dependency.

If we run also with `--reinstall`:

```
rosdep install --simulate --reinstall --from-paths ~/workspaces/project/src --ignore-src
#[apt] Installation commands:
  sudo -H apt-get install ros-indigo-hokuyo-node
  sudo -H apt-get install libeigen3-dev
```

And it additionally shows an already installed non-ROS dependency.

We now install missing dependencies using rosdep:

```
rosdep install --from-paths ~/workspaces/project/src --ignore-src
```

And after that, we run it again with `--simulate --reinstall` options:

```
rosdep install --simulate --reinstall --from-paths ~/workspaces/project/src --ignore-src
#[apt] Installation commands:
  sudo -H apt-get install libeigen3-dev
```

It successfully lists the non-ROS dependency, but doesn't list the ROS dependency.

Running it without `--reinstall` just gives emply output, as all dependencies are already installed:

```
rosdep install --simulate --from-paths ~/workspaces/project/src --ignore-src
```

So its seems that rosdep `--reinstall` only lists/reinstalls non-ROS packages. Is that the expected `--reinstall` behaviour?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251732/how-can-generate-a-list-of-dependencies-from-the-src-folder-of-a-workspace?/) by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 329 on 2017-01-11

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the `--simulate` and `--reinstall` with `--ignore-src` to get the list I think you want like this:
`rosdep install -si --reinstall --from-path ~/path/to/src/`

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2017-01-12**:
Wow. I completely missed that option. However, that command is only showing me the unmatched dependencies and not the ones already installed. Using `rosdep install -s --reinstall` and `rosdep check` gives me the same list of packages (and I know for sure that plenty of packages where installed).

**Comment by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) on 2019-04-12**:
I am also struggling to figure this out, all I'm trying to do is generate a list of apt package dependencies from a set of multiple ros packages.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-04-12**:
If you have packages already installed on your system you can also use `rospack depends <PACKAGE>` however it won't do the rosdep resolution automatically to alias it to the debian package names. So that combined with `rospack list` and a little scripting can get you what you want. Or you can use the rospkg
and rosdep python API to write a python script that does exactly what you want. This is what we do on the buildfarm.

**Comment by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) on 2019-04-13**:
Thanks for responding! I did end up hacking up a mess of a bash script, I'll try the python API next time. If it comes out clean, I'll try to share it here. Thanks!